# scipy.optimize.curve_fit - TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m))

Tags: python, numpy, scipy-optimize

I am attempting to optimize parameters of a function I've written that rotates points and then transforms them from pixel location to mm from a particular point. I am encountering `TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m))` which other questions on SO seem to indicate that I have more parameters than data points. The data I am feeding it has 26 sets of x,y coords. Can anybody see where I'm going wrong with the code below?

Thanks in advance

```
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np
import math

def px_to_mm_v4(coords, cf_x, cf_y, nudge_x, nudge_y, center_x, center_y, rotate_degrees):
    
    ## set lower left loc
    ll_x = center_x - (127.76/2/cf_x) ## lower left x location in pixels
    ll_y = center_y + (85.47/2/cf_y) ## lower left y location in pixels
    
    ## unpack coordinates
    x,y = coords
    
    ## rotate points around center
    rotate_radians = math.radians(rotate_degrees)
    x_rotated = center_x + math.cos(rotate_radians) * (x - center_x) - math.sin(rotate_radians) * (y - center_y)
    y_rotated = center_y + math.cos(rotate_radians) * (x - center_x) + math.cos(rotate_radians) * (y - center_y)
    
    ## convert px to mm
    x_converted = (x_rotated - ll_x) * cf_x + nudge_x
    y_converted = (ll_y - y_rotated) * cf_y + nudge_y

    ret_x = x_converted
    ret_y = y_converted
    ret = (ret_x,ret_y)
    return ret


x_px = np.array([1723,1530,1334,1135,943,747,548,2520,2322,2120,1921,1726,1530,1331,1132,937,741,545,346,349,352,355,358,358,361,361,148])
y_px = np.array([596,791,986,1176,1373,1569,1769,1973,1967,1967,1964,1962,1964,1967,1967,1967,1962,1964,1967,1769,1569,1373,1178,986,791,602,2162])

x_mm = np.array([80,70,60,50,40,30,20,120,110,100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,0])
y_mm = np.array([80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,0])
test_coords_tup = (x_px,y_px)
points_to_fit_tup = (x_mm,y_mm)

cf_x_test = 0.05072
cf_y_test = 0.05076
nudge_x_test = -2.2
nudge_y_test = 2.1
center_x_test = 1374
center_y_test = 1290
rotate_degrees_test = 1.4

params0 = [cf_x_test,cf_y_test,nudge_x_test,nudge_y_test,center_x_test,center_y_test,rotate_degrees_test]

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(px_to_mm_v4, test_coords_tup, points_to_fit_tup, p0=params0)
```

Edit: running the code gives back the error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SO_example.py", line 48, in <module>
    popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(px_to_mm_v4, test_coords_tup, points_to_fit_tup, p0=params0)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 784, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 414, in leastsq
    raise TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m))
TypeError: Improper input: N=7 must not exceed M=2
```

Comment: In searching the other SO did you come across the idea of posting the **full** error, with traceback?

Comment: @hpaulj right you are, see trace added to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `leastsq` docs

```
func callable
    Should take at least one (possibly length N vector) argument and 
    returns M floating point numbers. It must not return NaNs or fitting 
    might fail. M must be greater than or equal to N.
```

Comment: In response to this I have gotten the optimization to work by minimizing using lmfit